# Pointwise Convergence of a Piecewise Function with seemingly odd domain

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have the following function sequence:

$$ f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
-1 & -1 \leq x \leq -\frac{1}{n} \\
nx & -\frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{1}{n} \\
1 & \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

And I'm attempting to find where the sequence congerges pointwise in order to then determine uniform convergence. But I seem to be having a fundamental misunderstanding, because it seems to me that as $n \to \infty$ the ranges for my x disappear. The first domain becomes $ -1 \leq x \leq 0$, the second $0 < x < 0 $ and the third $0 \leq x \leq 1$ however that means at $ x = 0$ $f(x)  = -1 \text{ or } \infty \text{ or }1$ That simply cannot be the case, unless the whole thing is simply undefined at $ x = 0$ and then my $f(x)$ becomes

$$ 
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    -1 & -1 \leq x < 0 \\
    0 & x = 0 \\
    1 & 0 < x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: What is the value of $f_n(0)$ for all $n$? So what should be the limit?

Comment: The first case should be $-1\le x\le\color{red}-\frac1n$. The domain of each $f_n$ is certainly $[-1,1]$, so nothing disappears$

Comment: @user160738 $f_n(0) = 0$ So does that mean that I should add a 3rd case to my $f(x)$ to include 0 at $x=0$ ?

Comment: @user25758 Clearly $f_n(0)$ is converging pointwise to $0$ , so yes.